# Is it possible to set individual frame durations in Python Plotly for an animation?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am working in Plotly graph objects and am trying to plot an object moving over the globe. During this process, each latitutde/longitude has a time value assigned to it but the time steps between each point is not always the same and as such, for the animations purposes, I would like to assign different frame durations to mimic this. If I had a list of all ideal frame durations, would there be a way to feed this into Plotlys code?

Here is example code utilizing plotly and pandas with a single duration:

```
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Scattergeo()],

    layout = [go.Layout(height = 300, margin = {"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0},
        updatemenus=[dict(type="buttons",
                          buttons=[dict(label="Play",
                                        method="animate",
                                        args=[None
                                            , dict(frame=dict(duration=5, redraw=True) ,
                                                         tranisiton=dict(duration=4),
                                                         fromcurrent=True,
                                                         mode='immediate')
                                              ])])])],

    frames = [go.Frame(
        data = [go.Scattergeo(
            lat = pd.Series(Latitude[k]),
            lon = pd.Series(Longitude[k]),
            mode="markers",
            marker=dict(color="blue")

        )],
    )
    for k in list(range(df['Simulation_Time'].size))
    ])
fig.show()
```